# How do I make the program account for indexes which don't exist in the array-list

Tags: java

My program is supposed to be passed 2 array-lists, arrivals and duration, and should return the number of events that can basically take place without overlap. However, a-lot of testcases are not being passed because the program does not count the duration after the final arrival of the arraylist.

Below is what I have so far:

```java
class Results {
    public static int maxEvents(List<Integer> arrival, List<Integer> duration) {
        int counter = 0;
        if (arrival.size() == 0) {
            counter = 0;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < arrival.size() - 1; i++) {
                if (arrival.get(i) + duration.get(i) <= arrival.get(i + 1)) {
                    counter++;
                } else if (arrival.get(i) == arrival.get(i + 1)) {
                    counter++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

I have tried to the following but not only did it not pass the current failed testcases but also caused alot of the ones that were successful to fail as well:

```java
else if (i == arrival.size()-2) {
    counter++;
}
```

To show the expected testcase is the following:

```
arrivals = [1,3,3,5,7]
duration = [2,2,1,2,1]
```

The first person arrives at 1, presents for 2 hours, then leaves. 2 people arrive at 3 but only one is allowed to present for 2 or 1 hours. The next person arrives at 5, presents for 2 hours. The final person arrives at 7, and presents for 1 hour. The answer output should be 4 as 4 people are able to present.

Comment: Don't compare Integers with == . Use equals

Comment: Would you mind providing a failing and a success test? Keep the code to minimal incase you have things you cannot share. But just from this its not very clear ( at least for me ) what your two input lists mean and why you need that minus

Comment: oh just realised what you said @Eran. You cant use equals on primitives.

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis an `Integer` is not a primitive

Comment: yes but in this case if you see the code its `int counter` and List#size() method which both return primitives

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis in the for loop he is using `==` on `Integer` so Eran is right.

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis I see 2 `Integer`s being compared with `==` in `arrival.get(i)==arrival.get(i+1)`. Different `Integer` instances might have the same integer value, so `==` will return `false` while `equals` will return `true`.

Comment: Ye @divjo I noticed that a bit later.. i was looking on the other 2 which are int comparison

Comment: I have updated a test case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input looks something like this:

```
List<Integer> arrival = new ArrayList<Integer>();
arrival.add(10);
arrival.add(12);
arrival.add(15);
arrival.add(17);
arrival.add(20);

List<Integer> duration = new ArrayList<Integer>();
duration.add(3);
duration.add(1);
duration.add(2);
duration.add(4);
duration.add(3);
```

I would recommend adding a value which stores the closest available time so you don't need to access two elements of your list at each step:

```
public static int maxEvents(List<Integer> arrival, List<Integer> duration)
{
    int counter = 0;
    Integer nextTime = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrival.size(); i++)
    {
        if(nextTime <= arrival.get(i))
        {
            counter++;
            nextTime = arrival.get(i) + duration.get(i);
        }
    }

    return counter;
}
```

This would make sure that each element in your list gets properly tested.

Comment: Your version of the program works but does no solve the problem of the last arrival being counted as a counter++.

Answer (score 0):

The rules seem to be:

- An arrival must end at most at the next arrival.
- Or the next arrival must be the same, then the next arrival is skipped (not considering its duration).

Expected:
- The data is sorted, by arrival.

These rules are slighty weird. For instance your algorithm does not take into account
when an arrival is repeated more than two times - but that is your homework.

What is easiest to handle the last case *after* the loop.

```
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i < arrival.size()-1; i++) {
          if (arrival.get(i) + duration.get(i) <= arrival.get(i+1)) {
              counter++;
          } else if (arrival.get(i).intValue() == arrival.get(i+1)) {
              counter++;
              i++;
          } 
      }
      if (i < arrival.size()) {
         counter++;
      }
```

When `get(i)` returns an Integer `<=` will ensure the int value is taken (is called *automatic unboxing* and uses `Integer.intValue()`. For `==` simply the `Integer` are compared, and in general only the integers -128 .. 127 will be cached as unique object.
Probably `Integer.valueOf(200) != Integer.valueOf(200)`.

To prevent such a pitfall, use plural names for the lists: `arrivals` and `durations`, and use help variables:

```
int arrival = arrivals.get(i);
int nextArrival = arrivals.get(i+1);
```